# Sinon.js mocks not recognizing methods

Tags: typescript, mocking, sinon

I'm currently using sinonjs with mocha for the test framework.  I'm trying to mock out a class, but it doesn't seem to recognize the methods.

Example:

```
module ModuleA{
    export class ClassA {
         public funciton1() {
              //do something
         }
    }
}

it.only("test1", function () {
    var sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    var mockClassA = sandbox.mock(ModuleA.ClassA);

    mockClassA.expects("function1").once();
    mockClassA.function1(); 
});
```

However, It throws an exception

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property function1 as function
```

I'm new to sinonjs so there is a good chance that I might be using it incorrectly.  Function1 is defined in ClassA, so the code is creating a mock for ClassA and then saying that it expects the function1 to be called on the mock.  I'm not sure why it can't find function1 as a function.

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mock` method takes instance of the object as a parameter and you're passing a function (class declaration). Use `new` keyword to create an instance:

```
var mockClassA = sandbox.mock(new ModuleA.ClassA());
```

Comment: Didn't realize that the stub class needs to wrap a real instance of the object. Thanks